# phpBB 3 documentation in .CHM format

Tags: documentation, phpbb, phpbb3

Does anyone has phpBB 3 documentation in .CHM format, please share!
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick search shows no one having done the legwork yet. So...

**Step 1:** extract the PHPBB3 documentation. (or [spider it](http://www.phpbb.com/support/documentation/3.0/) from online)

**Step 2:** use a utility like [HelpSmith](http://www.helpsmith.com/htmlhelp.php) to bundle it up

Good luck. I've worked with PHPBB, and now prefer other php5 projects by far